# Deleting entire database

Tags: ios, core-data

Can we delete an entity and all the related entities in core data IOS.

I have an entity `A` and entities `B` & `C` related to `A`.  `D & E` is related to `B`.

How to entirely delete the database instead of individually fetching `A,B, C, D & E` each time and delete?

Is there any method to delete only `A` which ensures deletion of all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the delete rule of the relationships to "Cascade". Then deleting A results in automatically deleting B and C. Deleting B results in deleting D and E...

Answer (score 0):

You set the ***delete rule*** on the user entity side to cascade. When the user entity is deleted, all the other entities held in relationships with the delete rule cascade will be deleted as well.